# Using retrieved data in textarea is causing extra whitespace in the beginning

Tags: php, html, laravel, textarea, laravel-blade

I have a textarea in my form and every time I post it, it adds an extra whitespace in the beginning (so every time I post the form and save it to database, it adds one more whitespace at the beginning)

To clarify the scenario, I am adding the code for the whole cycle.

---

First, this is how my form and textarea is. It works fine with this...

```
<form id="myForm" action="" method="post">
    <textarea id="history" rows="25" class="form-control" name="history">DefaultVal</textarea>
</form>
```

---

However, to show the data saved in database, I use Laravel's `{{ }}` for echoing the value.

```
<form id="myForm" action="" method="post">
    <textarea id="history" rows="25" class="form-control" name="history">@if ($history) {{ str_replace('<br />', '&#13;', $history->value) }}@endif</textarea>
</form>
```

---

After I post the data to my controller, I would receive the textarea with `\r\n`, thus I used nl2br first in order to add `<br />`, and then removed `\r\n` tags with `str_replace()` accordingly:

```
public function receivePost(Request $request) {
     $newHistoryText = nl2br($request->history);
     $newHistoryText = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n\r", "\r", "\n"), "", $newHistoryText);

     // save to database
}
```

---

At this point, saving it to database works. Retrieving the data also works and it doesn't add any whitespaces anywhere. However as soon as I display it inside the textarea like this, as soon as I post, it creates additional whitespace at the beginning:

```
<form id="myForm" action="" method="post">
    <textarea id="history" rows="25" class="form-control" name="history">@if ($history) {{ str_replace('<br />', '&#13;', $history->value) }}@endif</textarea>
</form>
```

---

To be more precise:

A) using dd() for retrieved data before returning the view.

[image]

B) dd the posted form data in controller (`dd($request->history)`):

[image]

---

I couldn't figure out where this issue is caused from. I know it would happen if I didn't write `<textarea></textarea>` on the same line, but I did. The php tag is also on the same line (which I believe causing the problem) but I couldn't find any other way to display the data inside the textarea.

Comment: I'm not a laravel guy, but  can you trim the posted data prior to insert, to ensure there are no leading spaces?   eg; plain ol PHP ` $var = trim($_POST['history']);`

Comment: I tried trim, but nothing seems to changed :/ I think it's adding the whitespace in the html, in textarea. Because just before returning the view, if I `dd($history->value)` (as $history is Eloquent), it's showing no leading whitespaces. As soon as I return the view and use it with `@if`, it creates extra whitespace. Even though I delete it, after I post, it still adds that leading whitespace

Comment: try use {!! !!} instead of {{ }}

Comment: @LipeTuga I tried it also, unfortunately no luck; same result as before. I think it's because of `@if .... @endif`, but couldn't figure out how to overcome this problem

Comment: Ahhhh found it! `@if ($history) {{ str_r...`, there was a spacing just after if's parenthesis. Should use it as: `@if ($history){{ str_r...`